# Proving $P(A\cap B\mid C) = P(B\mid C)P(A\mid B\cap C)$

Tags: probability, solution-verification

So, if $P(A\cap B\mid C)>0$, how do we prove:

$$P(A\cap B\mid C) = P(B\mid C)P(A\mid B\cap C) \,\,?$$

I started off with Bayes Theorem and said $$\frac{P(A\cap B)P(C\mid A\cap B)}{P(C)} = P(B\mid C)P(A\mid B\cap C)$$
but apparently that is wrong :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using definitions left hand is
$$P(A \cap B|C)=\frac{P(A \cap B \cap C)}{P(C)}$$
and right hand is
$$P( B|C)P(A| B \cap C) = \frac{P(B\cap C)}{P(C)}\cdot\frac{P(A \cap B \cap C)}{P(B\cap C)}$$
When brought probabilities are defined.

Comment: You need at least $P(C)>0$ for this

Comment: so youre saying P(A∩B∩C)/P(C) = P(B∩C)/P(C)⋅P(A∩B∩C)/P(B∩C)?

Comment: also yes, absolutely Henry thank you

Comment: @Henry. As I understand it comes from that in OP we have $P(A \cap B|C)>0$. Additionally we need $P(B \cap C)>0$. Nevertheless I added last sentence.

Comment: @mizerex. Yes, we simply shorten  $P(B \cap C)$, assuming it is $>0$

Comment: cool thanks man!

Answer (score 3):

In general we have:

$P(X \cap Y) = P(X|Y)\cdot P(Y)$

As three different instances of this general theorem we have:

$P(A\cap B \cap C) = P(A\cap B|C)\cdot P(C)$

and:

$P(A\cap B \cap C) = P(A|B \cap C)\cdot P(B \cap C)$

and finally:

$P(B \cap C) = P(B|C) \cdot P(C)$

From here, it's easy!